# Copy Outlook sent item to Windows folder using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I am creating a VBA macro launched from Excel to create outgoing mails using variables within the Excel file.

Once sent, we require the mail to be copied to a network directory rather than a public mail file (e.g. "R:\Site Reports*****").

I have seen several threads for macros based within Outlook allowing mails to be copied to public folders within Outlook.  I can't see anything for a macro based in Excel that could copy a mail outside of Outlook.

Comment: If you reference the Outlook object model and get ahold of an `Outlook.Application` instance, it doesn't make much difference whether you're in Outlook or Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the mail item to the disk first and then move it to a network share using the [FileInfo.MoveTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.moveto%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method which moves a specified file to a new location, providing the option to specify a new file name.

The [MailItem.SaveAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868727.aspx) method saves the Microsoft Outlook item to the specified path and in the format of the specified file type. If the file type is not specified, the MSG format (.msg) is used.

You can handle the [ItemAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869609.aspx) event of the Items class which is fired when when one or more items are added to the specified collection. So, you can track when items are added to the Sent Items folder (i.e. sent).

Finally, you may find the [Automating Outlook from Other Office Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869289.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article helpful.